# viewing site from server

Tags: asp.net

**ok i'm trying to put my asp.net website onto my university's web server but when visiting my webpage I get the following problem:**

```
Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required     
to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your 
configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as  
allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be 
caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 13:     </connectionStrings>
Line 14:     <system.web>
Line 15:         <roleManager enabled="true" />
Line 16:         <authentication mode="Forms" />
Line 17:         <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />

Source File: F:\users\1010033\co5027\web.config    Line: 15
```

I can't get this working at all. I presume it's to do with the user security and roles I set up in Visual Studio but I have no idea about what to do to fix the problem. Bear in mind I don't have access to ISS as that is all set up by the university.

I have a second `web.config` file in a folder called `AdminSecured` in my root folder which holds all the secured pages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need set up your virtual directory in the control panel of your hosting.

Answer (score 0):

I've only seen this if you haven't set your site as an Application in IIS or if you have two web.configs on the root.